# How do I make an iOS app's Build Identifier dynamic?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on some Swift code with my children.  We would like to work from a shared codebase, so that we can each grab the code, then build and install the app onto our phones.

When I grab the source code my daughter wrote, I get the errors:

`The app ID "com.example.OurApp" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.`

and:

`Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.example.OurApp'.`

If I change the Bundle Identifier value in XCode to something globally unique, everything works.  But I don't want to do that because then it is confusing what changes should be committed and/or shared.

The Bundle Identifier value seems to be statically attached to the project files, and those project files need to be checked into to source control, which means that we have to manually muck with that value before we can build and sign our app so that we can run it on our phone.

We each have a developer account that gives us the ability to sign an ipa with our certs, which allows us to install builds on our phone.

I think I want to make the Bundle Identifier dynamic based on the machine or user that is building it.

I think I want to type `com.myfamily.$(SOME_ENV_VARIABLE).OurApp` into the Bundle Identifier box in XCode, and then commit that file so that any of us can just grab the code, mess with the code, then install the signed ipa on our phone without changing any of the XCode project file values.

No matter what I type into the "Bundle Identifier" box in XCode, the resulting value in the plist within `Build/Products/.../Info.plist` is garbage. Even changing some .swift files causes this plist to change to some junk value.

How do I make it so that I can share an XCode project with my family such that we can each sign and run the app, without changing or git-ignoring any of the project files/plists?

We are using XCode 8.3.x and running iOS 10.

Comment: You can make two targets with different  `bundle identifier`

Comment: @vp2698 how can I make those targets be the default for those specific machines?